# Converging sequences with inequalities

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that if $f,g,h:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ are bounded sequences such that $f\le g\le h$ and $\liminf(f)=\limsup(h)$, then $f$, $g$ and $h$ converge.

So I know that if a sequences limsup=liminf then it converges but struggling how to relate this to the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The supremum of a function $f$ (a sequence is a function) on a set $S$ is always greater than or equal to $f$ on the set $S$. Similarly, the infimum of $f$ is smaller than or equal to $f$ on $S$.

Thus,
$$\inf(f) \leq f \leq g \leq h \leq \sup(h)$$

Since $\liminf(f)=\limsup(h)=L$, this implies that $\lim f = \lim g = \lim h$, by the squeeze theorem.

(Notice that $f$, $g$ and $h$ are all "squeezed in" by $\inf(f)$ and $\sup(h)$)

Comment: Thanks so much !!

Comment: @JJBurt You are welcome!

Comment: Your answer says that $\inf(f)=\sup(h)=L$. When I first read that, I was confused as this meant that the statement shows that $f = g = h$. However, this is not the case as the correct statement to make is that $\lim \inf(f)= \lim \sup(h)=L$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you for your observation. I will correct it.

Comment: @Doublelift If I answered your question, you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the given order among $f,g,h$, we have
$$ \liminf f\le\liminf g\le \liminf h\le\limsup h$$
and 
$$ \liminf f \le \limsup f\le\limsup g\le \limsup h$$
As the first and last terms are equal, we conclude 
$$ \liminf f=\liminf g= \liminf h=\limsup h$$
and 
$$ \liminf f = \limsup f=\limsup g=\limsup h$$
and hence all limsups and liminfs are equal and ar lims

Comment: Thanks so much !!!!! I always get confused with how the inequalities can relate.